# Hibernate inheritance and 2nd level cache proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, hibernate-mapping

Simple app works wrong with following entity structure

```
@Entity(name="some_table")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn( name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING )
abstract class EntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EntityA")
@Cacheable
class EntityA extends EntityBase {
    @Column
    private int aColumn;
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EntityB")
@Cacheable
class EntityB extends EntityBase {
    @Column
    private int bColumn;
...
}

@Entity(name="holder_table")
@Cacheable
class HolderEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    EntityBase holdedEntity;

    ...
}
```

For first load or without cache everything works well

After loading of HolderEntity instance from cache, holdedEntity field initialised by object with type EntityBase (abstract class).

**Pseudocode:**

```
def a = HolderEntity.get(1)
assert a.holdedEntity.class!=EntityBase //ok
a = HolderEntity.get(1) // load from cache
assert a.holdedEntity.class!=EntityBase //fails (actually EntityBase_$$_jvstbbe_0)
```

During loading from cache hibernate construct entity using special logic:
for field it detect class type by variable type (it's EntityBase class) instead of discriminator (*final Type[] types = subclassPersister.getPropertyTypes();* in **DefaultLoadEventListener**) and call method
**SessionImpl.internalLoad(String entityName, Serializable id, boolean eager, boolean nullable)** witch "instantiate" abstract class and init fields by data from hibernate cache

It works same for lazy & eager loading of holdedEntity
Class type stored in **AbstractEntityPersister.EntityMetamodel**. It looks like, field type for cache is static, but it's should depend on instance of field

How to solve it without disabling of hibernate L2 cache?

Hibernate 4.3.8 (4.3.6 & 4.3.11 tested also)

Update:
[test class](https://github.com/demon101/hibernate-l2-inheritence/blob/master/src/test/java/com/test/hibernate/L2InheritanceTest.java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Hibernate uses proxies for lazy associations. If you want to disable proxies, you need to add the [@Proxy](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/) annotation to your entity class mappings:

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)
```

If you run [this GitHub test](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/cache/L2InheritanceTest.java), you' see that `@Proxy(lazy=false)` solves your problem.

Comment: But after loading the object from the cache, the `holdedEntity` is not a proxy in debug mode?

Comment: test class has been created  https://github.com/demon101/hibernate-l2-inheritence/blob/master/src/test/java/com/test/hibernate/L2InheritanceTest.java

Comment: It works as I told you. Run the test I uploaded on GitHub. You can find the link in the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I also test it. Now I'm try to add same configuration in Grails, but without success http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932479/grails-proxylazy-false-analog